# unable to locate a file in / directory using find command

Tags: linux, find

I have created a dummy file in /  named 123.test
Tried all simplest method to locate it using find command, none works to find a simple file.. What's wrong ?

Created dummy file 123.test

```
$ ls -l /
total 104
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 Dec 18 17:17 123.test      <-------------
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Jan 20  2021 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct  2 23:21 boot
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 23670 Mar 11  2020 desktopfs-pkgs.txt
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root  4040 Dec 18 06:57 dev
drwxr-xr-x 112 root root 12288 Dec 18 06:57 etc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct  4 01:04 home
```

search1: **i thought failed due to no root right**

```
$ find / -name 123.test
find: '/opt/containerd': Permission denied
find: '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections': Permission denied
find: '/etc/polkit-1/rules.d': Permission denied
find: '/etc/lvm/cache': Permission denied
find: '/etc/cups/ssl': Permission denied
find: '/etc/samba/private': Permission denied
```

search2:  Hence used sudo to find, but not working at all.

```
[user1@user1-pc /]$ 
$ sudo find . -name 123.test
[sudo] password for user1: 
^C

[user1@user1-pc /]$ 
$ sudo find / -name 123.test
[sudo] password for user1: 
^C
```

Why find command just does not working /root  ?

Comment: search1: no, you didn't fail due to missing rights. Any user should be able to see `/123.test`. Did you let `find` finish? This could take a while! I bet you just interrupted `find` before it had a chance to find `/123.test`.

Comment: I have tried many times ... it just either output tons of rubbish or just don't yield result in quicker time.. I mean . the file is located on top of /root directory, it is not hidden in nested folder, why should it take minutes and minutes to locate it ?  of course i can't find it.. i won't want to spend 10 minutes for such a simple search !

Comment: $ ls -lb
total 104
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 Dec 18 17:17 123.test
there is nothing behind the file... it is just a simple filename.

Comment: you ignore that it's not a simple search at all. You're literally asking find to go through everything in `/`, and if that's a directory, look (recursively) into everything in there, and so on… your `123.test` just comes very very late.

Comment: I see what you meant Marcus. the search is actually goes into a directory into the most depth of it to look for such a pattern, and then another depth .. it is not actually do a most surface search then dive deep down.

Comment: exactly! That's also what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ^C
> ```

You killed find before it was finished searching. So, nothing is wrong here; it just can take forever (literally, find can't know about recursive mounts) to search /.

You should add `-x` to the options to research searching to the same filesystem mount (and not start searching things like /sys or /proc).

Your problem is the following: you know that it's likely (or certain) that a *breadth-first search* will be faster than a *depth-first search*, but `find` only does DFS.

Comment: Understood. Thx